# What is the optimal way of organizing each-to-each comparsion operation on large amounts of data?

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I have big amounts of data, essentially big vectors, that need to be compared with each other to determine their relationship with each other. Vectors are held in a local sqlite database.

What is the optimal way to organize the process?

What i have been doing until now was loading keys for all the vectors, and then iterating through their combinations, extracting data and comparing them, and saving result to the database after each comparsion. However, the process takes a long time.

I presume, quicker ways of doing this would be loading the data in bulk and then performing the comparsion in parallel. How could that be done right? Are there some papers on the subject, where optimal methods are described?

I am using sqlite database, c++ as a language and qt framework. The data being compared and comparsion method are, essentially, black box - they are from external library.

Comment: This isn't particularly clear.  Are you saying that you need to perform N^2 comparisons?  Do these need to be performed in a particular order?  What are you doing with the results?

Comment: More like (n^2 - n)/2, but yes. Order is not important - whatever gives the minimal amount of requests for the database is best. results (just a number from 0 to 1) are to be stored in the database.

Comment: I'd suggest to download data from database first, not invoking queries for each row. It will improve performance a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build up a queue of "working assignments", i.e. of combinations of data elements to test and consume them from threads within a thread pool (`QThread` and family come to mind).

Working Assignments could look like this:

```
class WorkingAssignment {
public:
    WorkingAssignment(DataType *lhs, DataType *rhs) : a(lhs), b(lhs) {}
    ResultType execute() const {
        return Compare(a, b);
    }

private:
    Vector *a, *b;
};
```

So a thread dequeues one assignment, calls `execute` on it, enqueues the result (perhaps together with identifiers for the data elements) into a result queue. Another (single) thread is responsible to consume the results and do whatever it is you wanna do with that data.

There are almost infinite possibilities to generalize this approach, e.g. pass a predicate to compare the data to the `WorkingAssignment`, diverse kinds of queues (perhaps some combinations are more important than others), ...

Comment: How should the size of the vector be chosen?

Comment: @Srv19: I had the impression that you wanted to compare a bunch of vectors to each other. Updated the answer. Also: If comparisons of single data elements take only a short time, it could be worthwile to experiment with vectors of varying length, that's true.

Comment: I presumed by vectors you meant something like std::vector<datatype>. My data type contains vector of floats, though. I am currently doing something like you described, but with QTConcurrent:mappedReduced which is fed enumerable of pairs {left element index,right element index}, performs comparsion in the map function and puts results in the database reduce function

Comment: That doesn't sound bad at all; it's basically a ready-made version of my idea. So the only optimization I currently see is getting all data from the database in bulk and writing all results in bulk, too.

Comment: If so - how should the size of bulk be chosen?

Comment: If your data size is larger than the memory size of your machine, you'll have a problem, because it will get rather hard to partition the data such that you can compare each item with each other item. Otherwise, I'd suggest to query from or send to the database as much data as possible, filling up the machine's memory as much as possible (while keeping it from swapping, of course)